# .net shortest string regular expression

Tags: .net, regex, string, shortest

How to find shortest string, first occurance it should return

I have this string. I m looking for td whose value contains  blabla with closing td. For ex:

```
  <tr blabla><td>blabla big content</td></tr><tr><td>thisisnot</td></tr>
```

I want only this string

```
  <tr blabla><td>blabla big content</td></tr>
```

I m using this regex in .net

```
<tr.*><td>blabla.*</td></tr>
```

I m new to regex...

Can any one tell me the way out.

Comment: Obligatory [you do not parse HTML with a regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) link.

Comment: No it is a very small html content which i m trying to parse. Just treat it as plain text instead of html.

Comment: In the immortal words of Mike Holmes, "If you're going to do something, do it right the first time." Don't use a regex to parse HTML, even if it's small, because these things never stay small. Use an HTML parser.

Answer (score 6):

Regex is by nature greedy - it will try and match the longest string that satisfies the pattern.

You need to use non-greedy quantifier in your pattern. So instead of "*" use "*?", and then use groupings to "capture" the match. The anonymous capturing of items is done by enclosing the group you want to capture in a set of parenthesis. The following seems to do the trick:

```
(<tr.*?><td>blabla.*?</td></tr>).*
```

This will create a capture group that you will need to query the regex result for.

Answer (score 0):

Use `(?<=<td>)[^<]+` as the regex, then do a length comparison on the matches.